# pandas dataframe extension resetting its state

Tags: python, pandas

I am extending a pandas dataframe with custom methods.

I would like to define a class attribute that can be reused in all subsequent calls until I explicitly decide to change it. 
Instead, the class attribute in question is reset after the first call.

This reproducible example explains the issue I am facing.

```
import pandas as pd

@pd.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor("extend")
class FeatureAccessor:
    def __init__(self, pandas_obj, source = 'database'):
        self._obj = pandas_obj
        self.source = source

    def add_ten(self):
        return self._obj + 10

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6], 'C': [7, 8, 9]})
    print('The original source is', df.extend.source)
    df.extend.source = 'local'
    print('The new source is', df.extend.source)
    df = df.extend.add_ten()
    print('After manipulation, the source was reset to ' + df.extend.source + '. I want it to be local')

# The original source is database
# The new source is local
# After manipulation, the source was reset to database. I want it to be local
```

I would like `self.source` to remain set to `local`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `add_ten()` function returns a **new** dataframe. This new dataframe get initialized with the default source `'database'`.
You'll need to set the source of this new dataframe like so:

```
def add_ten(self):
    temp = self._obj + 10
    temp.extend.source = self.source
    return temp
```

Another possibility is to do the addition inplace:

```
def add_ten(self):
    self._obj.iloc[:,:] += 10
    return self._obj
```